# Does Google Document AI Form Parser learn from Human In The Loop?

Tags: machine-learning, ai, parsing, google-cloud

I've just started using Document AI's [Form Parser Processor](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_form-parser) to extract fields from some forms I have.

They are about 40 pages long, always follow the same format, and generally seem pretty easy to parse as the tool got it about 90% right straight away. The problem is that the parser is dragging the item number into the value.

For example: "1. Address: 1600 Pennsylvania Ave." would come back with:
key = "Address:"
value = "1. 1600 Pennsylvania Ave."

I'm using HITL which allows for the human to correct the result but I can't tell if/how that gets fed back to the system to stop making that error every single time. I've got several hundred of these docs per month to process and if I have to make that fix on every field on every doc forever I might as well not use the parser at all.

Does anyone know how to feed the corrections back into the machine?